# If condition can be replaced with guard statement if value is non-nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method called `isClassroomFull()` which returns either true or false. I have implemented as follows.

```
if (isClassroomFulll()) {
  navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
  return
}
```

Shall I also safely use guard statement as well? My concern is `isClassroomFull()` does not return non-nil value.

```
guard isClassroomFulll() else {
  navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
  return
}
```

Comment: That's fine, `guard` isn't only for nil. As long as it's a Bool or unwrapping optionals it's fine.

Comment: Wait wait "isClassroomFull() does not return non-nil value" -- so can it return nil, or is it just a true/false?

Comment: It returns either true or false.

Comment: Yeah that's fine.

Comment: Note, your `guard` statement is doing the opposite of the `if`.  The `guard` is popping when `isClassroomFull()` returns `false`.

Comment: @vacawama, I have realized it when I have been testing it, so funny that I did not catch it up at the beginning. Thanks for point out!

Comment: Also, from a style point of view, see if you can turn `isClassroomFull()` into a computed property `isClassroomFull`